# Silverlight 4 WCF Ria Service Timeout

Tags: silverlight, wcf, timeout, ria

I’ve asked this question before without getting to the solution, but since I have done a lot more testing and debugging, and have new information, I figured I would ask again in hopes of getting to the bottom of this once and for all.

My domain service is timing out after 1 minute.  I have read all the posts and seen how to create a partial class and explicitly set timeout values, and I have done exactly that, but I still get timed out after one minute.  **The caveat to this is that after explicitly setting the timeout in my partial class/method, I no longer receive the standard timeout error. Instead I get this:**

> {System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: NotFound.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_DisplayClass5.b_4(Object
>   sendState) at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_DisplayClass2.b_0(Object
>   sendState) --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state) at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)}

Here is my partial class that I set the timeout values in.  I have debugged this and know for certain that these values are being set prior to making  the call into the service.  The service method I am working with is TestTimeout().  It does nothing but sit and wait until the above exception is thrown - exactly one minute after the call.

```
  public partial class MyDomainContext
  {
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
      var proxy = (WebDomainClient<MyDomainContext.IMyDomainServiceContract>)this.DomainClient;
      proxy.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
      proxy.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
      proxy.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
      proxy.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

    }
  }
```

My test function on the server:

```
[Invoke]
public void TestTimeout()
{
  while (true)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100); // after one full minute, I get the above exception
  }
}
```

Could something else be timing out?  I see the same problem on my local development machine as well as my production server running IIS7.  I’m baffled as to what this could be.  I don’t think the timeout values are being ignored since I no longer get the standard timeout exception.  I just think there is another place that a timeout is happening.

Any ideas?

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought, have you tried making your asp.net session timeout explicit, may be its on one minute..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the constructor of your proxy:

```
InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
```